# Setting a Thumb's cursor when IsDragging = True

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a control template for a Thumb defined in a Resource Dictionary.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
            Cursor="SizeWE"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

The ControlTemplate is implemented in a style I call `GridColumnHeaderGripper` and this style is implemented in another Resource Dictionary

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
    <DockPanel>
    <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Margin="0,0,-8,0"
            Cursor="SizeWE"
            Style="{StaticResource GridColumnHeaderGripper}" />
    etc...
```

It works great, however, when I begin dragging the Thumb, then the cursor changes from "SizeWE" to "None". I saw another post similar to this on StackOverflow that suggested a Trigger to set the Cursor.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

However this solution didn't work for me.

From what I can understand is that we can override the cursor using the `Mouse.OverrideCursor` static property. Is it possible to set this static property using a Trigger? Is there anything I can do to change the cursor when dragging a thumb?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add 'Cursor' attribute where you actually declare thumb.  

<Window x:Class="ThumbCursor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ThumbCursor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="template" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
            Cursor="SizeWE"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Thumb x:Name="thmb" Height="50" Width="100" Cursor="SizeWE" Template="{StaticResource template}" DragDelta="thmb_DragDelta"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi, 
I've tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work. The cursor still changes to "None" when I begin Dragging. Also the Thumb is implemented in a Resource Dictionary, so I can't use codebehind